# laravel sending two email instead of single while making custom verification template through appServiceProvider

Tags: laravel

Here is the source code of Appservice Provider   ..when i commented out code inside boot function then laravel send me just a single email of laravel  default email verfication template ...but that code inside  boot function sending two email instead of one email ..laravel sending custom verfication template but twice

```
 <?php
    
    namespace App\Providers;
    
    use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
    use Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\VerifyEmail;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;
    use Carbon\Carbon;
    use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
    use App\User;
    
    class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
    {
      /**
       * Bootstrap any application services.
       *
       * @return void
       */
      public function boot()
      {
        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
        
        VerifyEmail::toMailUsing(function ($notifiable) {
               
              $verifyUrl = URL::temporarySignedRoute(
                    'verification.verify',
                    Carbon::now()->addMinutes(Config::get('auth.verification.expire', 60)),
                    [
                        'id' => $notifiable->getKey(),
                        'hash' => sha1($notifiable->getEmailForVerification()),
                    ]
                );
                 $user = User::whereEmail($notifiable->getEmailForVerification())->first();
    
                return (new MailMessage)
                    ->subject('Verify your email address')
                    ->markdown('emails.verify-email', ['url' => $verifyUrl, 'user' => $user]);
                   
            });
        
        
      }
    
      /**
       * Register any application services.
       *
       * @return void
       */
      public function register()
      {
        $this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
        return base_path().'/';
      });
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you put a block of codes in `AppServiceProvider`, it runs for every requests. maybe you run it two times (means you have two requests when you want to execute that). trace your requests from start to end of this process.

Comment: app is live ...i am coding in  cpanel ... how do i trace my request in live server.... i need to make custom verification email ...how can i do that

Answer (score 0):

Just try to remove

```
$user->sendEmailVerificationNotification();
```

From RegisterController.php in registered function

In my case:
Before

```
protected function registered(Request $request, User $user)
    {
        if ($user instanceof MustVerifyEmail) {
            $user->sendEmailVerificationNotification();

            return response()->json(['status' => trans('verification.sent')]);
        }

        return response()->json($user);
    }
```

After

```
 protected function registered(Request $request, User $user)
{
    if ($user instanceof MustVerifyEmail) {
        return response()->json(['status' => trans('verification.sent')]);
    }

    return response()->json($user);
}
```

Comment: Could you try to explain why this resolves the duplicate email issue? What is going on?